# SweetAlert2 - overflowing page vertically + defaulting CSS to style="overflow-y: auto;"

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert2

I'm using the latest version (v11.4.23) of SweetAlert2 from https://sweetalert2.github.io/ via the code below:

```
<script>

<?php $FailureMessageCaption = "<span class=\'highlight\'>Welcome</span> to Initial Setup!" ?>;                     

                                Swal.fire({
                                          icon: 'info',
                                          title: "Welcome to Initial Setup",
                                          html: <?php echo "'" .$FailureMessageCaption ."'" ?>,
                                          confirmButtonText: 'I understand',
                                          confirmButtonColor: '#4568ba',
                                          allowEscapeKey: true,
                                          allowOutsideClick: false,
                                          timer: <?php echo $MessageTimeoutNormal ?>,
                                          timerProgressBar: true,
                                          showClass: {
                                            popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeInDown'
                                          },
                                          hideClass: {
                                            popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeOutUp'
                                          }                                       
                                        })
                                        
                                        
</script>
```

The messsage box is working fine without error, however each time it displays, it causes my page to overflow (grow) vertically by around 80px. When it's closed/disappears, the overflow vanishes, and the page length returns to normal.

In developer tools it would seem SweetAlert2 is overriding the CSS, specifically injecting `overflow-y: auto` for classes *swal2-container swal2-center* and *swal2-backdrop-show*.

I have looked into the SweetAlert2 CSS as well as my own CSS, but cannot force it to stop. If I add `overflow:hidden` to the container on my page, then it still overflows verticially.

Full CSS modified by SweetAlert2 below.

It doesn't matter if I fire the message box within `<body>` or not.

Removing *showClass*, *hideClass*, or *timerProgressBar* has no bearing.

Any ideas how to stop it tripping?

**UPDATE:** I can have `height: 100%;` in `<body>` but in my wrapper I need to set an absolute height (i.e. `height: 1332px;`) to make this disappear. Unfortunately setting an absolute height is only a temporary fix :(

```
<div class="swal2-container swal2-center swal2-backdrop-show" style="overflow-y: auto;">
    <div aria-labelledby="swal2-title" aria-describedby="swal2-html-container" class="swal2-popup swal2-modal swal2-icon-info animate__animated animate__fadeInDown" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-live="assertive" aria-modal="true" style="display: grid;">
        <button type="button" class="swal2-close" aria-label="Close this dialog" style="display: none;">×</button>
        <ul class="swal2-progress-steps" style="display: none;"></ul>
        <div class="swal2-icon swal2-info swal2-icon-show" style="display: flex;">
            <div class="swal2-icon-content">i</div>
        </div>
        <img class="swal2-image" style="display: none;">
        <h2 class="swal2-title" id="swal2-title" style="display: block;">Welcome to Initial Setup</h2>
        <div class="swal2-html-container" id="swal2-html-container" style="display: block;">Enter your data into the fields contained within this form. Once all data has been input, please <span class="highlight">click the Continue button</span> below in order to proceed with Initial Setup!</div>
        <input class="swal2-input" style="display: none;">
        <input type="file" class="swal2-file" style="display: none;">
        <div class="swal2-range" style="display: none;"><input type="range"><output></output></div>
        <select class="swal2-select" style="display: none;"></select>
        <div class="swal2-radio" style="display: none;"></div>
        <label for="swal2-checkbox" class="swal2-checkbox" style="display: none;"><input type="checkbox"><span class="swal2-label"></span></label>
        <textarea class="swal2-textarea" style="display: none;"></textarea>
        <div class="swal2-validation-message" id="swal2-validation-message" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="swal2-actions" style="display: flex;">
            <div class="swal2-loader"></div>
            <button type="button" class="swal2-confirm swal2-styled swal2-default-outline" aria-label="" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(69, 104, 186);">I understand</button><button type="button" class="swal2-deny swal2-styled" aria-label=""
                style="display: none;">No</button><button type="button" class="swal2-cancel swal2-styled" aria-label="" style="display: none;">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div class="swal2-footer" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="swal2-timer-progress-bar-container">
            <div class="swal2-timer-progress-bar" style="display: flex; transition: width 20s linear 0s; width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```